# CakePHP helpers and i18n

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, multilingual

I have some questions about cakePHP, I spent long time Googling for a solution and as I didn't find any I'm not sure I'm taking the right approach.

So, I have a menu/sitemap which is part static (xml file - i10n) and part dynamic (database i18n)

I've been asked to cache the menu so that:

1. A component creates a cache xml file of the whole menu for each language if it doesn't exist
2. An helper creates a cache html formatted from the xml file created from the component
3. The layout uses the helper to add the menu in the page

Questions:

- How do I get the list of available languages from the helper and from the component?
- Is this

  ```
  $this->L10n = new L10n(); $this->L10n->lang
  ```

  the correct way to get the actual language?
- If I import the helpers/component in the app_controller instead of typing them in each controller

  ```
  class AppController extends Controller {
      var $components = array('menu', 'otherComponent');
      var $helpers = array('menuCache');

      function beforeFilter(){
          $this->menu->doSomething();
      }
  }
  ```

I get a `call to undefined object $html` for the `echo $html->charset();` in the layout

can't understand why...

Comment: I don't know about the L10n problem, but the reason why you're getting the "undefined $html" is because you wrote $helpers = array('menuCache'); By default, cake puts HtmlHelper there as well, you need to do it too (and Javascript and others you use). i.e. $helpers = array('Html', 'Javascript', 'menuCache', etc...);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Configure::read('Config.language')`. A part of the CakePHP cookbook states:

> The current locale is the current value of Configure::read('Config.language'). The value of Config.language is assigned in the L10n Class - unless it is already set.

I18n, the class responsible for translation using `__()`, uses `Config.language` so, unless you override it in `bootstrap.php`, that variable contains the selected language. Actually, even if you override it, it will still contain the used language (there might be inconsistencies because I10n is not really aware of the change but I never ran into any).

To get a list of languages, you can use `L10n::catalog()`. I'm not sure it's what you're after, however, since it lists all languages CakePHP knows about, not only the languages that actually have a translation in `app/locale`.